# System wide proxy with encypted ISA server request

Tags: debian, networking, linux-mint, proxy

I recently install Linux Mint Debian on my computer. It is working fine and I also have internet. But just firefox is able to get through the proxy.

After some research I found out that the ISA server in my network is automatically refusing all authentifications that are not encrypted. So setting a system wide proxy with using `export HTTP_PROXY="http://user:passwd@proxy:port/"` Will not work.

So how do I get my system to send encrypted requests to the ISA server?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Install a bridge proxy like [cntlm](http://cntlm.sourceforge.net/) or [ntlmaps](http://ntlmaps.sourceforge.net/).  Both are available in Debian.